# CartoDB Torque dynamic timeout

Tags: carto, torque

I have been trying to create a torque animation where the points on the map fade out at different times.  I have a table with 'start_date', 'end_date', and a 'day_count' which is a count of the number of days between the start and end date.

Is there a method of setting up the Torque visualization so that when the time slider gets to the end dates for each point the points will disappear. I have not seen any similar examples on cartodb.com, or github.

Answer (score 1):

Torque is only aware of when an event "happens": a point will appear in the date that it occurred, but there isn't any function or attribute to say Torque "hey! keep this point appearing until X date".

What you can do is to replicate your point to make it occur all along the period in which you're interested to show.

If your start_day is 01/01/2015, and your start day is 01/03/2015, you could have in your table:

```
Geometry - Date    
Point A - 01/01/2015
Point A - 01/02/2015
Point A - 01/03/2015
```

Depending on your data range, you might need to add even more points at several times of the days.